# Trouble with "function" to verify data

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

It was supposed to return the newsFeed array with any database (username + password), but it works only with the first user, even if the others are right.

I'll let the link to CodePen. Thanks for all

https://codepen.io/kennedyrmenezes/pen/OJbRKay

```
var database = [
    {
        username: "andrei",
        password: "supersecret"
    },
    {
        username: "sally",
        password: "123"
    },
    {
        username: "ingrid",
        password: "777"
    }   
];

var newsFeed = [
    {
        username: "Bobby",
        timeline: "So tired from all that learning"
    },
    {
        username: "Sally",
        timeline: "JavaScript is sooooooo cool!"
    },
    {
        username: "Mitch",
        timeline: "JavaScript is pretty cool"
    }
];


function isUserValid(username, password) {
    for (var i=0; i < database.length; i++) {
        if(database[i].username === username && 
           database[i].password === password ) {
        return true; 
        }
    return false;
    }   
}



function signIn(username, password) { 

    if (isUserValid(username, password)) {
        console.log(newsFeed);
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, wrong username and password!");
    }
} 

var userNamePrompt = prompt("What's your username?");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("What's your password?");

signIn(userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are returning false inside your for loop instead of outside. If the i = 0 iteration fails, then you'll return false. Instead, you want to only return false if all of the iterations fail.

```
function isUserValid(username, password) {
    for (var i=0; i < database.length; i++) {
        if(database[i].username === username && 
           database[i].password === password ) {
        return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```